# Copy file to Firefox user profile with batch?

Tags: batch-file, firefox, deployment, scripting, firefox-addon

I am trying to create an active setup to copy files to all users profile after application launch.

Using this command, I am unable to copy file(s) to user profile

The problem is that although no one uses profiles, the "Default" Profile have a random prefix name (24xwe234.default \ 45qw324w.default).

```
xcopy "C:\Temp\123.cfg" C:\users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default" /d /y
```

How can I copy the file to the ****.default/ Folder via batch script?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).  You failed to post the resulting output from running your script.

Comment: The `*.default` part of your target path looks horribly wrong. You must decide what the target file or directory name is.

Comment: @jwdonahue *.default is a profile name... the firefox profle name will be different for everyone like 123dfg32.default

Comment: Yes, there's a reason for that. Your script will have to figure out what it is first and then overwrite it.

Comment: BTW: You're going to need elevated administrative privileges to access other user's profiles.

Comment: You should accept CristiFati's answer if you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ***Administrative privileges*** (in order to read/write other users *%HOMEPATH%*), then everything below could be applied to other users, else it's limited to your own user **only**.

Although *xcopy* is a pretty advanced command, I don't think it can handle *wildcards* at destination in this scenario (also didn't you miss an "*******" after "*.default*"?).

One alternative would be to use a *.bat* script that iterates (using [[SS64]: FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) (or [[MS.Docs]: for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for))) over the *.default** like dirs (corresponding to *Firefox* profiles - not an expert on this area, could there be more than ***1***?) and copies the file (using good old [[MS.Docs]: copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy)) in each of them (if any).

*code.bat*:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions

set _SOURCE_FILE="C:\Temp\123.cfg"

set _TARGET_USER=%USERNAME%
set _FIREFOX_PROFILES_PATH="C:\Users\%_TARGET_USER%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"

for /f %%f in ('dir /b "%_FIREFOX_PROFILES_PATH:"=%\*.default*"') do (
    echo Copying %_SOURCE_FILE% to "%_FIREFOX_PROFILES_PATH:"=%\%%f"
    copy /y %_SOURCE_FILE% "%_FIREFOX_PROFILES_PATH:"=%\%%f"
)
```

As it is now, the script copies the file in the *default* *Firefox* dir(s) for **current** user only.

Again, with *Administrative privileges*, it can be extended to iterate all existing users, and do the same thing for each of them (well, it could be extended anyway, but it will still do only what's doing now, when run by a regular user).

But anyway, the question (or, at least the step that posed problems) is about the current user's *.default* profile.

Comment: You don't actually need the extra quotes and quote replacement code. Or the for loop for that matter.

Comment: @jwdonahue: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: `set _test=Has spaces` followed by `set _test` yields "_test=Has spaces". In the absence of quotes in the variable value, you can avoid having to strip them everywhere. Of course `dir "program files"\amd` is the same as `dir "program file\amd".  I am struggling to recall the one liner that gets rid of the for loop...

Comment: @jwdonahue: It's OK when only dealing with variables. Try (as we are on *Firefox* topic) `set _FIREFOX_EXE=c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`, and then  `%_FIREFOX_EXE%` (as a different command, obviously). Then try it *dblquoted*. I'm sure that *Google* would yield tons of results on this issue. This has been an issue since like (Program Files*). That's why I avoid paths with spaces, and also write code that handles them properly.

Comment: @CristiFati, yes, but you can put the quotes on when you dereference the variable, so why waste all the bandwidth on adding/removing quotes in your example?

Comment: It's a nit, forget I mentioned it.

Comment: @krishna: if it answers your question, please mark this as an answer (so that others can see it)

Comment: @jwdonahue: This works  on **any** *Win* path. I tend to present my scripts this way because you never know... when someone runs the script from some funky path, and without the space handling would simply break. To be honest, I didn't study the performance implications for quote adding/removal, but relying on batch (**involving paths**) to execute millions of times per second, seems just wrong.

Comment: I used to work on a team that had thousands of scripts to maintain and we tended more towards highest readability over anything else.

Comment: @jwdonahue: really? over functionality? Anyway I'm not going any further with this; feel free to downvote my answer (if you haven't done it already);  I'd appreciate a comment, explaining why, as well - in order to get better in the future. Cheers!

Comment: No of course not. If you can get the same function with easier to read script, that's to be preferred. In other words, no extraneous complexity allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180765/discussion-between-cristifati-and-jwdonahue).